# Finding constant of proportionality in differential equations

Tags: exponential-function

Cane sugar turns to dextrose.  This is proportional to the amount of cane sugar yet to be converted.  100g of cane sugar is added and 12 g are converted into dextrose during the first hour.  How much dextrose will be present in the juice after three hours?

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=kx\\\\P=pe^{kt}\\88=100e^{k(1)}\\k=-0.12783$$

Evaluating at t=3 gives an answer of 68.1472. The answer is supposed to be 31.85 and I have no idea where I am going wrong.

Am I messing up in the values I am using?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know much about the application but could it be because 68.1472 would be the amount unconverted and 31.85 is the amount converted? The two numbers add up to 100

Comment: That JUST dawned on me!!!  Thanks for confirming!